# JQuery, XML, and a period in the tag name

Tags: jquery, xml

I subscribe to a third party web service that returns a lot of records and the tag names have a period in them.

Example:

```
<row rownumber="1">
    <a.FirstName>John</a.FirstName>
    <a.LastName>Smith</a.LastName>
</row>
<row rownumber="2">
    <a.FirstName>Jane</a.FirstName>
    <a.LastName>Doe</a.LastName>
</row>
```

I'm using JQuery to go through the records and that works just fine.

I can get the current row number from the element and it loops through all 2,000 records.

However, what I can't do is get the value inside the tag.

```
$(xml).find('row').each(
    function(){
        alert( $(this).attr('rownumber') );  //WORKS GREAT! 
        //but
        alert( $(this).find('a.FirstName').text() ); //does not work 
    }
);
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,
D

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the selector you use `a.FirstName` will be interpreted as an achor-tag with the class FirstName. If you have special characters in the tag-name (like your dot), you will have to escape the `.` with two backslashes in the selector.

The [jQuery documentation on selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) state the following:

> If you wish to use any of the meta-characters ( such as
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, you must
>   escape the character with two backslashes: \. For example, if you
>   have an element with id="foo.bar", you can use the selector
>   $("#foo\.bar").

Try this instead:

```
$(xml).find('row').each(
    function(){
        alert( $(this).find('a\\.FirstName').text() );
    }
);
```

Comment: Here was the solution: (put \\ before the period in the tag name) Example: alert( $(this).find('a\\.FirstName').text() ); //WORKS